# how to fix bug in the windows of elementary os

Tags: display, settings, applications

I'm using eclipse photon to program in java 8, and when I create a new class, package, I enter the settings, etc. It seems that these windows are inside a window, how can I solve this?[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue in Elementary OS](https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/244) due to their somewhat non-standard way of applying window decorations. Fortunately, there is a fix, but it must be applied on a per-application basis. In fact on the issue description itself on GitHub, there's a summary of how to fix it with [Eclipse as a sample](https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/244#issuecomment-452695835):

> For those wondering how to change the .desktop file appropriately, set:
>
> ```
> Exec=env GTK_CSD=0 <executable path>
> ```
>
> For example for Eclipse I did this:
>
> ```
> Exec=env GTK_CSD=0 /opt/eclipse/eclipse
> ```

So you'll want to edit the eclipse desktop file to add that `GTK_CSD=0` as an environment variable added before Eclipse executes.

You could also probably use [App Editor](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor/) to do the same, if you prefer a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to gtk3 with eclipse. If you force it to use gtk2 it works. Had a similar issue with dbeaver which is eclipse based.

Comment: how do you force it to use gtk2?